# Multi level Virtual include

Tags: php, html

I have a requirement in php file, I have one php file , say `file.php`, in that i am including one html file using

```
<!--#include virtual="/file1.html"-->
```

again in that `file1.html` , i am including contents from one more php file using virtual

```
<!--#include virtual="/file2.php"-->
```

Problem here is i am not getting contents of file2.php after include. am able to get only `file1.html` contents,

Note: Here `file1.html` is non-editable since its being included in many other files,

Comment: Is that the actual code? Those are commented out? Also is the `.html` file really php? Not sure how you include anything in html...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your server if include,cgi, expires Modules are enabled.

Another thing i am not sure about if ssi allow include a .php file because the  tag will only works on a .php file, but when you are including using SSI what it do is just copy whole code from the included file and paste into the main file , in your case which is html. which isn't feasible.

check out the 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes#Directives

and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

and if you are using nigx server for this project then including php file is possible please check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html

Hope this come helpfull.